# DataGridView not reflecting change on database

Tags: c#, datagridview, sqlite

My C# Datagridview does not show updated data.

This is a Winform, c# application using SQLite.  When my form is open, it is showing the data the way it looked before I updated a column on two separate rows using DB Browser for SQLite.  In the DB Browser when I execute this SQL: SELECT * FROM SPEAKERS, I see a 10 and a 13 in the column I changed (they used to be a 0 and a 2.  This column is defined as an INTEGER.

When I open that particular form, it shows the data in that column as a 0 and a 2.  Further down the grid I see 12's and 13's, etc. so it's not a formatting issue on the column.  On this form I have an hCDataset, an speakersBindingSource and a speakersTableAdapter.  When I right-click on the speakersTableAdapter and choose "Preview Data", it shows the hierarchy of the HCDataSet and the Speakers table under that with the selected object: HCDataSet.Speakers.Fill.Getdata() method.  When I hit the Preview button, the data looks exactly like on my datagrid.

Believe me, I've rebooted, closed everything, gone back into the DB Browser for SQLite and every time it opens up with the 10 and 13 in those columns, but it never shows up in the grid on my form with those new updated values in that column.

I thought I could take screenshots, but apparently not.  I can paste my screenshots into Paint and they look fine, but apparently when I copy from there and hit CTRL-G in this editor, they don't show up in this document.  Maybe I don't have high enough permissions or something.

I've read on other posts that people are having issues updating from the grid and not seeing the updates on the database.  I'm kind of having the opposite problem where I update the database, but for some reason the grid isn't showing it.

I've added the code where I'm showing you my connect methods and the code to query the database.  When I get to the 3rd row, it display the correct '10' from the RANK column!!

```
public static SQLiteCommand GetSqliteCommand()
{
    SQLiteConnection conn = GetSqliteConnection();
    return conn.CreateCommand();
}

public static SQLiteConnection GetSqliteConnection() 
{
    string dbPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "hc.db");
    string connectionString = string.Format("Data Source={0};foreign keys=true", dbPath);
    SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString);
    conn.Open();
    return conn;
}


//Now my code snippet to read the database and this DOES return the updated column!

GetLastUpdateSql = "SELECT * FROM SPEAKERS ORDER BY ID";

cmd.CommandText = GetLastUpdateSql;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

SQLiteDataReader reader;
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

int int1, int2, int3, int4, int5;
string fn, ln;

while (reader.Read())
{
    fn = reader["FIRST_NAME"].ToString();
    ln = reader["LAST_NAME"].ToString();
    int1 = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ID"]);
    int2 = Convert.ToInt32(reader["TYPE"]);
    int3 = Convert.ToInt32(reader["WARD"]);
    int4 = Convert.ToInt32(reader["RANK"]);
    int5 = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ACTIVE"]);
}
```

Comment: If you are actually retrieveg from the db you should see the current data. There must be something quite different going on, but it is hard to guess. Can you pull out the select from your app before it goes out and compare result with pasting it into the dbBrowser?

Comment: Could you please execute 'PRAGMA database_list' from your application and post the output?

Comment: I noticed if I run the PRAGMA database_list in DB Browser for SQLite, it returned 3 columns.  So I read those in my c# program and got:  SEQ = 0; NAME = "main"; and FILE = "C:\\HCSpeakers\\HCSpeakers\\bin\\hc.db".